# $a_1 = 2, a_2 =7$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(a_{n} + a_{n-1})$, Find $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

For this sequence:

$a_1 = 2~~~a_2 =7$

and $a_{n+1} =  \frac{1}{2}\cdot(a_{n} + a_{n-1})$

The questions asks to find the exact formula for the $n$th term of the sequence and hence find the limit as $n \to \infty$

They also gave us this formulae: http://puu.sh/ylNZ1/5e595930e0.jpg, I am not particularly sure how to use them though.

Anyways I tried listing out more terms and I found that

$a_3 = \frac{9}{2} ~~~ a_4 = \frac{23}{4}$

And I found out the difference between these terms is $5,\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{4}$ thus we can write $a_{n+1}=a_{n} + \frac{5}{2^{n-1}}$

I am not sure how to continue though.

Comment: That is a linear recurrence. Why not use $a_n=\lambda^n$?

Comment: @Arnaldo I am not familiar with sequences, and this is the first time I have ever come across a sequences question. So this is my working showing how I would have attempted it.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2085401/42969.

Comment: @MartinR The funny thing is that the question was asked by the same user.

Comment: @MathLover: Indeed, I had not noticed that! – But those questions have answers which *explain* how to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

it is $$a_n=\frac{1}{3} 2^{2-n} \left(5 (-1)^n+2^{n+2}\right)$$,try the ansatz $a_n=q^n$

Comment: How do you get this formula?

Comment: i have written this above $$a_n=q^n$$ and look into the Internet how one can solve lineare recurrence equations